# What should be the type of a RouteComponentProps to add additional attributes under props parameter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-tsx

I have the following component using react-router-dom:

```
<Route path='/restaurants/:id' render={props => (
  <Restaurant {...props} user={user} />
)} />
```

Now, in my `Restaurant.tsx` code, I can't seem to figure out what should be the proper type for `props` below:

```
const Restaurant = (props: RouteComponentProps<{id: string}>) => {
  const a = props.match.params.id;
  const b = props.user;

  ...
}
```

With the type `RouteComponentProps<{id: string}>`, `a` is assigned a value without error. However, that's not the case for `b`:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'RouteComponentProps<{ id: string; }, StaticContext, unknown>'
```

What should be the type of `props` so that I can get the extra attribute `user={user}` that's passed to the component using `props.user` without any type errors?

Comment: `RouteComponentProps<{id: string}> & {user: ...}`

Comment: This also works, thanks! I'm now wondering which is the better answer. That or using interfaces.. hmm..

Comment: Whatever you like more, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare interface for props of `Restaurant` component and extends `RouteComponentProps` interface.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface RestaurantProps extends RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }> {
  user: any;
}
const Restaurant = (props: RestaurantProps) => {
  const a = props.match.params.id;
  const b = props.user;
  return <div>Restaurant</div>
}

const App = () => {
  const user = {};
  return (
    <Route
      path="/restaurants/:id"
      render={(props) => <Restaurant {...props} user={user} />}
    />
  );
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG9EIBXGJAGidaQGFdIAdkgEwACjjABnOAF842XASLoYAWhzcoqgCa4yVKsBFIomdEkRJJMFMygoR4iFLhIAHmwHbpCFmz7gEEKOEpIAPIzA2gBccNZQRgDmsgB8DFRwcMySJrEOAJ4UlDJUaEHWlta29iJwALxwABRgobHIVXYOYqEAlPVp9BlwZQIVKPVwLc6SAHQgKDBoABYzYCj2ILNRRZkjFQBGE1NSM9kmO3BEMHYCcGHawABuKe02nSJhAPQPz1QllKVyvAAIJgMATRp9OoDIZ7eBnKATegyC5XG5NIaZMK+biYzKTBZLOoAIk+RA6NRgkk+0SixLxmSIXhMdXozV6-Tur2qXQYM35x0kcgRrIRck+KX++LgEqGPSKKKAA)

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks! Just wondering if there's a way to do this without using interfaces? Because initially, I thought RouteComponentProps has built-in features for those extra attributes.

Comment: No it doesn't, you are supposed to do it using type intersections