# Pass Object to a React Component using Link in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I was wondering if it is possible to pass an object as a parameter to a react-router-dom endpoint using react-router-dom-v6. I've seen some ways of doing it with Hooks but they require functions instead of components.

This is the main component handling the Routes

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { Page01 } from "./Page01";
import { Page02 } from "./Page02";

type TypeProps = { name:string }
type TypeState  = { }

class Main extends React.Component<TypeProps, TypeState> {

    constructor(props:TypeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={ <Home name="home"/> }/>
                        <Route path="/page01" element={ <Page01 name="page01"/> }/>
                        <Route path="/page02" element={ <Page02 name="page02"/> }/>
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Main name="main" />, document.getElementById("main"));
```

Then a basic component which is only handling the Link to method.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

type TypeProps = { name:string }
type TypeState  = { }

class Page01 extends React.Component<TypeProps, TypeState> {

    constructor(props:TypeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to={ "/page02" }>
                    <span>Go To Page 02</span>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export { Page01 }
```

And then an almost identical component at the other end which will need to receive this data.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

type TypeProps = { name:string }
type TypeState  = { }

class Page02 extends React.Component<TypeProps, TypeState> {

    constructor(props:TypeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to={ "/page01" }>
                    <span>Go To Page 01</span>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export { Page02 }
```

I've tried to pass the data with state

```
let paramData = {
    field01:"data01",
    field02:"data02"
}

<Link to={ "/page02" } state={{ paramData:paramData }}>
    <span>Go To Page 02</span>
</Link>
```

But I cannot receive it on the other end because the I'm using a component and not a function

Comment: You'll need to either convert to a React function component so it can use the `useLocation` hook, or you will need to create a custom `withRouter` HOC to do this for you and pass the `location` object along as an injected prop to your class component. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566486/8690857) with details. It's not in Typescript, but typing it should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

React Router provide [special props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) at Route component.

On [props location](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location) you can get property `state` contain data from `Link state`

at `constructor` of `Page02` you can get `state` with:

```
    constructor(props: TypeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        
        console.info(props);
        console.info(props.location);
        console.info(props.location.state);
    }
```

Comment: I may be missing something here but when I `console.log(props)` it doesn't have the location property, only name as defined in the TypeProps

Comment: You component `Page02` has been define inside `Router` ?

Comment: Yes it has, I will update the question to include that part

Comment: Do you can show the version of `react-router-dom`  you use please?

Comment: The exact version is `6.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

Can attempt use lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log(nextProps);
  console.log(nextProps.location);
}
```

I think you route `Page02` component has not good props type,
`react-router-dom` export interface `RouteComponentProps`
should be use with *Route Component*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link, RouteComponentProps} from "react-router-dom";

type TypeProps = { name:string }
type TypeState  = { }

type Page02Props = RouteComponentProps<TypeProps>;

class Page02 extends React.Component<Page02Props, TypeState> {

    constructor(props:TypeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };

        console.log(props); // should be {location: [Object], match: [Object], history: [Object], name: string }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to={ "/page01" }>
                    <span>Go To Page 01</span>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export { Page02 }
```

I dont find official documentation for react-router-dom + typescript,
but on a [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303245/what-should-be-the-type-of-a-routecomponentprops-to-add-additional-attributes-un)
can get `special props` with *good type* `Route Component`

Comment: The componentWillReceiveProps seems to be becoming redundant and the RouteComponentProps doesn't exist on react-router-dom. I really appreciate all of your help but I think the simplest solution is to just move over from Components to Functions